# Filter all files in directory for words that match multiple regexes

Tags: python, regex, glob, pypdf, os.path

I am trying to filter all files (pdf, txt,csv,ipynp, etc.) in my directory for words that match my regex expressions. So far I made a program(shown below) that can read csv and pdf files but the else statement, which reads all other files types keeps giving me an error(shown at the bottom). Am i typing something wrong after my else: statement?  I have tried everything but to no avail.

```
   import glob
import re
import PyPDF2
#-------------------------------------------------Input----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
folder_path = "/home/"
file_pattern = "/*"
folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern)

#Search for Emails
regex1= re.compile(r'\S+@\S+')
#Search for Phone Numbers
regex2 = re.compile(r'\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d')
#Search for Locations
regex3 =re.compile("([A-Z]\w+), ([A-Z]{2})")


for file in folder_contents:

    if re.search(r".*(?=pdf$)",file):
        #this is pdf
        with open(file, 'rb') as pdfFileObj:
            pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)  
            read_file = pageObj.extractText() 
            #print("{}".format(file))
    elif re.search(r".*(?=csv$)",file):
        #this is csv
        with open(file,"r+",encoding="utf-8") as csv:
            read_file = csv.read()
    else:
            with open(file,"rt", encoding='latin-1') as allOtherFiles:
                continue
    if regex1.findall(read_file) or regex2.findall(read_file) or regex3.findall(read_file):
        print ("YES, This file containts PHI")
        print(file)
    else:
        print("No, This file DOES NOT contain PHI")
        print(file)
```

I get an error saying IsAdirectoryError: [Errno 21] is a directory:  Do you know why this error message keeps showing whenever i run the code.

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IsADirectoryError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-fdb88fbf61ab> in <module>()
     29             read_file = csv.read()
     30     else:
---> 31             with open(file,"rt", encoding='latin-1') as allOtherFiles:
     32                 continue
     33     if regex1.findall(read_file) or regex2.findall(read_file) or regex3.findall(read_file):

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/jupyter_shared_notebooks'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try changing your `with open(file,"rt") as allOtherFiles:` statement to

```
with open(file,"rt", encoding='latin-1') as allOtherFiles:
```

Run the code again and see if you hit the same error. If there is still an error, we would have to try other encoding formats.

EDIT: 
To address your next error:

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: /home/e136320/jupyter_shared_notebooks
```

This is caused by a file or folder named `jupyter_shared_notebooks` inside your folder.
Because python does not know how to open `jupyter_shared_notebooks` since it does not have a file extension format. It is throwing this error.
To address this, you can try to

```
if '.' not in file:
    continue
else:
    with open(file,"rt", encoding='latin-1') as allOtherFiles:
        #rest of your code here
```

Comment: so it runs by now is giving a different error. I updated it in my questions above.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IsADirectoryError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-fdb88fbf61ab> in <module>()
     29             read_file = csv.read()
     30     else:
---> 31             with open(file,"rt", encoding='latin-1') as allOtherFiles:
     32                 continue
     33     if regex1.findall(read_file) or regex2.findall(read_file) or regex3.findall(read_file):

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/e136320/jupyter_shared_notebooks'

Comment: @JamesDavinport, I've updated the answer to solve your next error.

Comment: Last thing: do you know how to  pass along content that has latin1 and only accept plain text that is in readable format?

Comment: I do not understand your comment question here. Perhaps you could start another stackoverflow question on it? Also, did the next solution I provided solve your `IsADirectoryError` error? Please let me know. Thanks!